# Is it possible to filter permission sets by criteria?

Tags: permission-sets

I have been forced to make changes to long standing permissions, and I now have a user seeing more than he should.

I want to use a permission set to allow a specific user to see all opportunities that are only under a certain category.

He uses a custom sales profile, which works well for all other users, who can only see their own opps. The unique case is someone who wants to see all opps from all users under his product category.

Can I filter a permission set to limit visibility by my custom filed "Category" and or Sub Category?.

If so, how? If not what other choices do I have beyond making a profile?

Thanks for any advice
Bill

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to use a Sharing Rule, not a Profile or Permission Set. This assumes your Organization-Wide Default is Private for Opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your use case is all about record level visibility. It is nothing to do with permission sets.

To open up user's visibility to the record you need to use criteria based sharing rule or through apex coding, use Force.com managed sharing or apex managed sharing, provided you didn't already open up the access through **OWD** as `Public Read Write` or `Public Read Only`

[image: Sharing architecture]